# Web scraping multiple pages with python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, iteration

I got csv-file with numerous URLs. I read it into a pandas dataframe for convenience. I need to do some statistical work later - and pandas is just handy. It looks a little like this:

```
import pandas as pd
csv = [{"URLs" : "www.mercedes-benz.de", "electric" : 1}, {"URLs" : "www.audi.de", "electric" : 0}]
df = pd.DataFrame(csv)
```

My task is to check if the websites contain certain strings and to add an extra column with `1` if so, and else `0`. For example: I want to check, wether `www.mercedes-benz.de` contains the string `car`.

```
import requests
page_content = requests.get("www.mercedes-benz.de")
if "car" in page_content.text:
    print ('1')
else:
    print ('0')
```

How do I iterate/loop through `pd.URLs` and store the information in the pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need loop by data by [`DataFrame.iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) and then create new values with `loc`:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    page_content = requests.get(row['URLs'])
    if "car" in page_content.text:
        df.loc[i, 'car'] = '1'
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'car'] = '0'

print (df)
                          URLs  electric car
0  http://www.mercedes-benz.de         1   1
1           http://www.audi.de         0   1
```

Comment: A follow up: if the get requests fails - e.g. when the URL is missing or wrong, is it possible to keep the loop running? @jezrael

Comment: Hard questiom for me, but meed some silent error handling in python. I never use it, so I cannot give you some good advice. Sorry. Maybe try another question if still problem.